# Combining knn and svm for document categorization in R

Tags: r, svm, knn, categorization

I am working on automated news categorization. I have 3 classes with each class having 90+ documents. I have used KNN and SVM (linear kernel) to check their accuracy. KNN is giving approx 86%(k=1) which further increases by increasing k and SVM is giving 75 % accuracy.

I have read that we can combine KNN and SVM together to increase the accuracy but i don't know how to do it. I am using R language.

Comment: "I have read [...]" Where?

Comment: There is a research paper with title "msvm-knn: combining svm and k-nn for multi-class text classification"

Comment: Have you tried with a gaussian kernel?  Just a guess, but I would imagine it would be similar.

Comment: ya i tried and Gaussian is giving very poor results.

Comment: Maybe Ensemble learning?